# Find the value of $a$ such that the series converges.

Tags: calculus, summation

I have to find the value of a such that the following series converges:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\frac{1}{3}}\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n^a}\right|$$

First of all, I simplified the series with the respective asymptotic as follows: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\frac{1}{3}}\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^a}\right| \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\frac{1}{3}}\left|\frac{1}{n^a}\right|$$
Then, simplifying again, it results:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a-\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Which should converge for $a>\frac{4}{3}$, but I checked with Mathematica, which according to it, it is wrong.

Comment: Uhm... Are you sure $\left\lvert \frac1n-\frac1{n^\alpha}\right\rvert\sim \frac1{n^\alpha}$? That ain't looking right.

Comment: As @SaucyO'Path mentions, $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n^a}$ for all $a > 1$. Therefore, you could make a distinction into two cases, $a > 1$ and $a > 1$ and then you could get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: Mathematica is like a gun. Sure, it comes in handy every now and then, but it ain't no smarter than the dude using it.

Comment: Also, a very special thing happens at $a=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is wrong.

*(First of all, $a_n\sim b_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are not the same thing; the second, actually, does not mean anything. But that's not the main point...)*

Note that, as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\sin\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^a}
= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{6n^3} - \frac{1}{n^a} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$
so that
$$
n^{1/3}\left(\sin\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^a} \right)
= \left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}} - \frac{1}{n^{a-1/3}} \right) - \frac{1}{6n^{8/3}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{8/3}}\right)
$$
So for the series $\sum_n n^{1/3}\left|\sin\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^a} \right|$ to converge, you need the term in parentheses to cancel *(why?)*, which gives you what $a$ must be.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you take $a=1$, then $\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n\right\rvert$ behaves as $\frac1{n^3}$, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n\right\rvert}{\frac1{n^3}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\left\lvert\sin(x)-x\right\rvert}{x^3}=\frac16.$$So, take $a=1$ and use the fact that the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{n^3}$$converges.